# Memory Leak in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

i wrote the following code to scrape for email addresses (for testing purposes):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from crawler.items import EmailItem

class LinkExtractorSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'emailextractor'
    start_urls = ['http://news.google.com']

    rules = ( Rule (LinkExtractor(), callback='process_item', follow=True),)

    def process_item(self, response):
        refer = response.url
        items = list()
        for email in Selector(response).re("[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"):

            emailitem = EmailItem()
            emailitem['email'] = email
            emailitem['refer'] = refer
            items.append(emailitem)
        return items
```

Unfortunately, it seems that references to the Requests are not closed properly, as with the scrapy telnet console, the number of Requests increases by 5k/s. After ~3min and 10k scraped pages, my system starts swapping (8GB RAM).
Anyone got an idea what is wrong?
I already tried to remove the refer and "copied" the string using

```
emailitem['email'] = ''.join(email)
```

without success.
After scraping, the items get saved into a BerkeleyDB counting their occurrences (using pipelines), so the references should be gone after that.

What would be the difference between returning a set of items and yielding each item separately?

EDIT:

After quite a while of debugging I found out, that the Requests are not freed, such that I end up with:

```
$> nc localhost 6023
>>> prefs()
Live References
Request 10344   oldest: 536s ago
>>> from scrapy.utils.trackref import get_oldest
>>> r = get_oldest('Request')
>>> r.url
<GET http://news.google.com>
```

which is in fact the start url.
Anybody knows what the problem is? Where is the missing reference to the Request object?

EDIT2:

After running for ~12 hours on a server (having 64GB RAM), the RAM used is ~16GB (using ps, even if ps is not the right tool for it). The problem is, that the number of crawled pages is going significantly down and the number of scraped items remains 0 since hours:

```
INFO: Crawled 122902 pages (at 82 pages/min), scraped 3354 items (at 0 items/min)
```

EDIT3:
I did the objgraph analysis which results in the following graph (thanks @Artur Gaspar):
[image: Python Objgraph Backlink]

It does not seem that I can influence it?

Comment: Try using the objgraph package to find out what is keeping a reference to the first request.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I appended some output of the objgraph package!

Comment: That's not the first request.

Comment: But it is one of the first ~20 with a lifetime of (until now) 225234s (~62 hrs)

Comment: You're using a LIFO queue for requests it seems. That's normal. Though I would also recommend trying a FIFO queue (which I think is the default). What is actually an issue is that there's a reference to the very first request.

Comment: Oh, it seems you are right! But I have not influence on that haven't I? I will try to change it and report!

Comment: That's configurable in Scrapy, search the docs for it. Either way that's probably not what is causing the leak, what you should worry about is that the first request is still alive. Can you try using objgraph on it?

Comment: I finally made it. I used the FIFO disk queue which persists to harddrive instead of memory. This does not solve the problem of having too much data, but as the list of requests is huge but finite, all requests are eventually processed! thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You should still look into what is keeping a reference to the first request. Or did that stop happening?

Comment: indeed, the amount of queued requests is much less.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The final answer for me was the use of a disk-based queue in conjunction with a working directory as runtime parameter.

This is adding the following code to the settings.py:

```
DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1 
SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeue.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeue.FifoMemoryQueue'
```

afterwards, starting the crawler using the following commandline makes the changes persistent in the given directory:

scrapy crawl {spidername} -s JOBDIR=crawls/{spidername} [see scrapy docs for details](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html)

The addidtional benefit of this approach is, that the crawl can be paused and resumed at any time.
My spider now runs for more than 11 days blocking ~15GB memory (file cache memory for disk FIFO queues)

Answer (score 5):

I want to point out an update for Robins answer (can't reply in his post yet, low rep).

Make sure you use the new syntax for queue**s**, cause their proporsal is deprecated now. That "s" costed me some days to figure out what was wrong. The new syntax is this:

```
    DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1 
    SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
    SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you `yield` each item separately, the code is executed differently by the Python interpreter: it's not a function anymore, but a [generator](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Generators).

This way, the full list is never created, and each item will have its memory allocated one at the time, when the code that is using the generator asks for the next item.

So, it could be that you don't have a memory leak, you just have a lot of memory being allocated, roughly 10k pages time the memory used by a list for one page.

Of course you still could have a real memory leak though, there are [tips for debugging leaks in Scrapy here](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem. I found the tips for debugging leaks but the only information I get is, that Request objects increase in quantity massively.

Comment: I see, so you probably don't have a memory leak, you just need loads of memory, maybe setting up throttling, distributing the work or a little bit of each. =)

Comment: I tried throttling (even tried setting concurrent requests to 1) but the memory is still increasing, but slower :-)

Comment: @Robin how much of a delay did you put into it?

Comment: I used the Autothrottle function of scrapy using the default from the tutorial: AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5.0; AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60.0